# grpc compression isn't compressing on nodejs

Tags: node.js, compression, grpc

I was running node examples of grpc usage: greeter_server and client:

Server

```
var PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/../../protos/helloworld.proto';

var grpc = require('grpc');
var protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH,
    {keepCase: true,
     longs: String,
     enums: String,
     defaults: true,
     oneofs: true
    });
var hello_proto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).helloworld;

/**
 * Implements the SayHello RPC method.
 */
function sayHello(call, callback) {
  callback(null, {message: 'Hello ' + call.request.name});
}

/**
 * Starts an RPC server that receives requests for the Greeter service at the
 * sample server port
 */
function main() {
  var server = new grpc.Server();
  server.addService(hello_proto.Greeter.service, {sayHello: sayHello});
  server.bind('[::]:50051', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
  server.start();
}

main();
```

CLient:

```
var PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/../../protos/helloworld.proto';

var grpc = require('grpc');
var protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH,
    {keepCase: true,
     longs: String,
     enums: String,
     defaults: true,
     oneofs: true
    });
var hello_proto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).helloworld;

function main() {
  var client = new hello_proto.Greeter('localhost:50051',
                                       grpc.credentials.createInsecure(), 
                                       {"grpc.default_compression_algorithm": "grpc.default_compression_level": 2}
                                       );

  var user;
  if (process.argv.length >= 3) {
    user = process.argv[2];
  } else {
    user = 'world';
  }
  client.sayHello({name: user}, function(err, response) {
    console.log('Greeting:' + JSON.stringify(response));
    if (response) {
      console.log('Greeting:', response.message);
    }
  });
}

main();
```

For node mudels I was using the following configuration:

```
{
  "name": "grpc-examples",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "async": "^1.5.2",
    "google-protobuf": "^3.0.0",
    "grpc": "1.24.4",
    "lodash": "^4.6.1",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

According to https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/master/doc/compression.md
all messages from the client should have been compressed. But when I checked with wireshark, there was no compression applied. Seems like the client silently ingnores the settings. Which brings me to questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How to make it work?
3. Is there any programmatic way to make sure that provided settings were successfully applied?
4. And also is there any way to enable logging in grpc module so I could debug such thing?

Comment: `{"grpc.default_compression_algorithm": "grpc.default_compression_level": 2}` is not even syntactically correct JavaScript. There may be a copy/paste error there. I see that you did not set any compression settings on the server. That may have an impact here. And can you explain how exactly you evaluated the Wireshark output to determine whether the data was compressed.

Comment: I actually found that with those settings some of the messages get compressed but not all of them. Typically when several grps frames are packaged together, some of them get compressed. I have analyzed using wireshark grpc dissector by inspecting a compression bit. But those were not the messages from the example and the packet rate was much higher. The syntax was the same though. What is the correct syntax anyway?

Comment: If some of the messages are getting compressed, that means that compression is enabled. So, is that a different situation from the one in which you said "there was no compression applied"?

Comment: Yeah, it is. It turned out that the server side was using grpc-js library which does not support compression so I had to switch to node-grpc library. With which I started to see some compression, but now I am stuck with another problem discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68804598/why-does-grpc-convert-all-ipv4-addresses-into-ipv6-to-start-a-tcp-server
Should probably close current question.