# Why does grpc convert all ipv4 addresses into ipv6 to start a tcp server

Tags: server, grpc, ipv6

According to native GRPC implementation, here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_custom.cc#L381
all ipv4 addresses are changed into ipv6 before the socket is opened here:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_uv.cc#L191

At least on CentOS this leads to grpc server being unable to start listening.

Can anyone please clarify why was this conversion made, why not just forward all ipv4 and ipv6 addresses straight into the socket and let them be managed by their original addresses?
Right now I am considering commenting this conversion out because I need this server on the environment without ipv6, but I am not sure if I am going to break anything by doing this...maybe there is some hidden dependency on the fact that we are always listening on ipv6 address?

Comment: I think you may be confusing IPv4-mapped addresses with IPv6 addresses. They are IPv4 addresses in an IPv6 format (`::ffff:x.x.x.x`), but they are still IPv4 addresses. That is what dual-stack devices use so that addresses are in a consistent format.

Comment: Ok, but what if I am having a single stack device? would it hurt if there would be no wrapping? And isn't the address format something handled by the system? That's what what "sa_family" flag is for, isn't it?

Comment: Without IPv6 enabled, then you do not get IPv4-mapped addresses. You only get that if you have both IPv4 and IPv6 enabled (dual stack).

Comment: For some reason grpc does not detect that I don't have ipv6 turned on. Can you please suggest any way to signal grpc that there is no ipv6?

Comment: You are asking on the wrong SE site because this is a configuration question, not a programming question. You have IPv6 enabled, and you should be supporting and using both IPv4 and IPv6 at this time.

Comment: I don't have ipv6 enabled, that's why I am asking this question.

Comment: Yes, you have IPv6 enabled, which is why you get IPv4-mapped addressing, otherwise you would not. You need to ask about your configuration on the correct SE site. In any case, you _should_ be programming to support both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Ok, suppose I didn't have ipv6 enabled, then what routine would have been called in that case? I mean obviously there wouldn't be any "tcp_server_add_port" from
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_custom.cc#L339 called because it lacks any alternative strategy of not wrapping ipv4.

Comment: Ron Maupin, what should I do if it is impossible to program for both ipv4 and ipv6?